# MySQL - NOT IN produce unwanted result

Tags: php, mysql, join, not-exists, notin

I have tables below:

```
user
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  user_id    |  username   | Password | ...    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     1       |     a       |  ***     | ...    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     2       |     b       |  ***     | ...    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     3       |     c       |  ***     | ...    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     4       |     d       |  ***     | ...    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     5       |     e       |  ***     | ...    |
+-----------------------------------------------+

friends
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  f_id    |  user_id   | friend_id | ...       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     1    |     4      |  2        | ...       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     2    |     4      |  1        | ...       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     3    |     4      |  5        | ...       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     4    |     4      |  3        | ...       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I want to get all users that are available to be added as friends (in this case, the `user_id` of `1` will have 3 more friends to be added `(2, 3, 5)`. However, by using the following `SQL statement below` I only get 1 user `(4)` available to be added:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.user_id NOT IN 
(SELECT friends.friend_id FROM friends) AND 
user.user_id <> $_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
```

But this works great when I logged in as user 4 which there are no users available to be added. This is a bit tricky to me. Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need a `WHERE` clause in your nested query?

Comment: I tried too, but still does not work. I tried `WHERE friends.friend_id <> $_SESSION['id']` or would it be something else?

Comment: No - `WHERE friends.user_id = $_SESSION['id']` - You want to find people that *this user* is not already friends with, correct?  So you want to say `NOT IN` the list of people said user is friends with.

Comment: +1 for the question @tepkenvannkorn, interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

How about this:
(in else clause use an invalid id or the same id as the logged in user)

```
select * from users where id not in
(
   select (
            case
              when uid = 1 then id
              when fid = 1 then uid
             else 0
            end
          ) from friends where uid = 1 or fid = 1
) and id != 1 order by rand() limit 5;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12de1/62

---

One more way to solve this (but might not be an optimal solution):

Union query below might not be a costly query compared to complete join between two tables if number of friends an user has is less than total number of users in system.

Also don't forget to add index on `uid` and `fid` column of `friends` table.

```
select * from users where id not in 
(
     select id from friends where uid = 1
     union
     select uid from friends where fid = 1
) and id != 1 order by rand() limit 5;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12de1/40

Comment: The second option works great and simple. Thanks @Manu for this

Answer (score 2):

How about this? The `null` shows where user `4` shouldn't be adding user `4` as a friend.. Infact you can filter it out by `And FID is not null`. If you want to `select to be added friends` a particular user as per your `session id` then you can spcify that in another condition as well :)

Updated adding another join to make sure the names are shown for friends, not for ther user. As well as there's no longer `4` exists.

- ### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12de1/19)

Query:

```
select x.id, a.name, x.fid
from users a
join (
select u.id, u.name, f.fid
from users u
left join friends f
on u.id <> f.fid
and u.id <> f.uid) x
on x.fid = a.id
;
```

Results:

```
| ID | NAME | FID |
-------------------
|  1 |    b |   2 |
|  1 |    e |   5 |
|  1 |    c |   3 |
|  2 |    a |   1 |
|  2 |    e |   5 |
|  2 |    c |   3 |
|  3 |    b |   2 |
|  3 |    a |   1 |
|  3 |    e |   5 |
|  5 |    b |   2 |
|  5 |    a |   1 |
|  5 |    c |   3 |
```

For a specifi user e.g. `1`

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO USER 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12de1/14)

```
select x.id, x.fid, a.name
from users a
join 
(select u.id, f.fid
from users u
inner join friends f
on u.id <> f.fid
and u.id <> f.uid
and u.id = 1)x
on x.fid = a.id
;

| ID | FID | NAME |
-------------------
|  1 |   2 |    b |
|  1 |   3 |    c |
|  1 |   5 |    e |
```

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn try this out and comment please :)

Comment: I just got finished posting a similar answer.  This seems *way* better than mine! >.>

Comment: @RocketHazmat glad for the heads-up just noticed I have given the wrong link for the last query. :D

Comment: Instead of using a subquery on your 2nd example, you can just `JOIN` the `users` table again to get the usernames. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12de1/25

Comment: OP can check on the `explain plan` and decide ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12de1/33. I just kept the two queries in the original subquery method to keep consistency.

Answer (score 1):

What your SQL query is doing is:  Get all users where id is not equal to ANY friend_id and not the current user (I assume).

What you want, is to check that no records exist for the pair of friend_id and user_id in the friend table, so something like:$sql =

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.user_id NOT IN 
(SELECT friends.friend_id FROM friends WHERE friend.user_id = user.user_id) AND 
user.user_id <> $_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `NOT IN` with a subquery, you can try to `JOIN` the `friends` table.

I `JOIN`ed it twice.  Once where the `1` is the `user_id` and once where `1` is the `friend_id`.  Then I got all users that aren't friends with `1` or are `1`.

```
SELECT user.user_id,user.username

FROM user

LEFT JOIN friends AS fA ON fA.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN friends AS fB ON fB.friend_id = 1

WHERE user.user_id != 1
AND NOT (user.user_id <=> fB.user_id)
AND NOT (user.user_id <=> fA.friend_id)
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a7ae/30

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the where clause in your sub query to limit it to the current users friends that you're excluding.

```
$sql = "select * from user u 
    where u.user_id not in 
    (select f.friend_id from friends f where f.user_id = ".$_SESSION['id'].")
    and u.user_id <> ".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
```

I'd also like to recommend not using string concatenation to do this. PDO would be safer, you would have no risk of SQL injection.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u1.id u1_id
     , u2.id u2_id
  FROM users u1
  JOIN users u2
    ON u2.id <> u1.id
  LEFT
  JOIN friends f
    ON (f.fid = u1.id AND f.uid = u2.id)
    OR (f.fid = u2.id AND f.uid = u1.id)
 WHERE f.id IS NULL;
```